# Why does enter another input to my program give me different result?

Tags: c++

*Here is the problem:*

> `Input (1): 10, 10, 10, 10, 1 | Output: 4` 
> `Input (2): 80, 50, 30, 65, 47 | Output: 3` *(Wrong output)*

*Code:*

```
int mark, student = 0;
int i, sum = 0;
double avg;

for (i=1; i <= 5; i++){
    cout << "Enter the student " << i << " mark : ";
    cin >> mark;

    sum = sum + mark;
    avg = sum / 5;

    if (mark > avg) student++;           
}

cout << "\nRESULT : ";
cout << "\n" << student <<  " student get mark more than the average of quiz." << endl;
```

*The result for the input(2) should be 2*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first loop, the sum is 10 and the average is 2. You need to calculate the final average first, then do a second loop to count the passing students.

Comment: Calculate the total sum first. Store the individual marks in a vector, and loop over the vector to count the passing students.